# link server communication failure

Tags: sql-server

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "from server name" returned message "Unspecified error".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "from server name" returned message "Communication link failure".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "from server name" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 64, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.
```

ip in host file is exist

rpc ,dataaccess already set to true

but still while fetching data from another server , via linkserver , getting above error.

Comment: I had that happen one time when the server you are linking **from** ran out of available memory.  A reboot of the server fixed it in the short-term, a change to a "bad program" (non sql related) fixed it in the long-term.

Comment: still getting error,TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.Msg 64, Level 16, State 1, Line 0

Comment: Have you tried flushing the dns cache on the from server?

Answer (score 0):

Use the linked-Server IP address instead of name on your linked-server settings in sql server then check the linked-server's port on firewall and make sure that you can connect to it by management studio or other ways from your machine.